# How to Print number which is over ULLONG_MAX at Console ?

Tags: c++, console

I want to print "845100400152152934331135470251"  or "1071292029505993517027974728227441735014801995855195223534251"

but in C++ the max value of "Unsigned long long " is "18446744073709551615"

this is much less than which I want to print

please help me...

Comment: Something like `puts("845100400152152934331135470251");` or `std::cout << "845100400152152934331135470251" << std::endl;`?

Comment: ah! There's one thing I missed. 
I want to output the above values ​​through calculation of variables and variables

Comment: What variables are you using to calculate these values?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I would like to use "unsigend long long" whenever possible. I want to output the above value by adding two variables together ... I will exceed the value of "ULLONG_MAX" ..

Comment: I am solving the algorithm. "2 * N tiling" is a problem.
The problem is as follows

"How many ways can you tile a 2xn rectangle by 2x1 or 2x2 tiles?"

Input: Input is a sequence of lines, each containing an integer number 0 <= n <= 250.

output: For each line of input, output one integer number in a separate line giving the number of possible tilings of a 2xn rectangle.

I try to solve "Dynamic Programming Algorithm"

However, in solving the problem, when adding variables and variables, n will exceed ULLONG_MAX from 100 or more.

How can it be ???

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your problem is not about printing big numbers but storing them in variables (and maybe calculating on them).

On some compilers (GCC for example), you have variable types like `int128` that can handle numbers up to 10^38 (more less).

If this doesn't solve the problem, you'll have to write your own arithmetic. For example, store numbers in strings and write functions that will calculate on them (addition and subtraction is rather easy, multiplying medium (as long as numbers aren't really huge), dividing by big integers hard). Alternatively you can look for already made big integer libraries (on the Internet, c++ doesn't have built-in one).